# Iterate over rows in smartsheet and indent based on value in column using node.js

Tags: node.js, smartsheet-api

My Smartsheet and node.js world is expanding :-), but now something I don't know how to approach.  I have a flat structured smartsheet with around 1000 rows and I need to indent selected rows using node.js.  The system (for this example) is broken into three layers; Chapter, Section, and Paragraph.  I have a column (called Marker) which identifies the layer by name (see example below).

What I need to do is to indent the sections below the chapters, and the paragraphs below the sections.  Note that a chapter can contain multiple sections. (Also note that the example is just that. I can't give real data, sorry.)

[update 1 Aug 2021]

I am ALMOST there (tantalisingly close)...

I think that one of the last things I will need to do, before optimising and documenting, is to get the indent bit working.  My code is below...

```
//Initialise Var
var sheetno=1234567890123456;  //this is the sheet ID 
var colcount=0; 
var chap,sect,rowno;
var rowdetail="nothing";
var row_ids='';
var rowList=[];
var row_ids='';
var rowList=[];
var rowdetail='';
var guiderow='';
var sectrow='';
var optionupdate='';
var newsectline='';
var newguideline='';

// Set queryParameters for `include` and pagination
var options1 = {
      id: sheetno,
  queryParameters: {
      pageSize: 1000,
    includeAll: true
  }
};

    // Load the sheet we are interested in
async function indent() {
    console.log("Starting process.  Please wait...");
    smartsheet.sheets.getSheet(options1)
    .then(async function(sheetInfo) {
        var rowCount=sheetInfo.totalRowCount;  //variable to hold the number of rows
        var totcolcount=sheetInfo.columns.length;  //variable to hold the number of columns
        var colcount=totcolcount-1;  //This accounts for arrays starting at the zero position.
        console.log("row count is ", rowCount, ". Column count is ", totcolcount)
        // iterate through rows in the sheet and make sure they are in the right order
        for (var i=0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            rowdetail=sheetInfo.rows[i].id;
            var rowloc=sheetInfo.rows[i].rowNumber;
            rowList[rowloc]=rowdetail;
        }
        // iterate through5 rows in the sheet
        for (var j=1; j < rowCount; j++) {  //change from 16 to rowCount when running in production
            var options2 = {
                sheetId: Number(sheetno),
                rowId: Number(rowList[j])
            };
            await procrow(options2,j,colcount);
            await sleep(3000);
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

function procrow(options2,j,colcount) {//Return your promise and let it be controlled outside of function
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            smartsheet.sheets.getRow(options2)
            .then(async function(row) {
                var rowid = row.id;
                console.log("j=", j, ", colcount=", colcount, ", Rowid = ", rowid, ", Guideline rowid=", guiderow, ", Section rowid=", sectrow, ", Newguideline=", newguideline, ", Newsectline=", newsectline );
                if (row.cells[colcount].value == "guideline") {
                    console.log("Found guideline");
                    if (newguideline==0) {
                        guiderow=rowid;
                        newguideline=1;
                        newsectline=0;
                    }
                    else {
                        // close off the general rows
                        optionupdate= {
                            sheetId: sheetno,
                            "rowId": rowid,
                            body: [{"parentId": sectrow, "toBottom": true}]
                            };
                        // close off section
                        await updateRow(optionupdate);
                        optionupdate= {
                            sheetId: sheetno,
                            "rowId": rowid,
                            body: [{"parentId": sectrow, "toBottom": true}]
                            };
                        await updateRow(optionupdate);
                        guiderow=rowid;
                    }
                }
                else if (row.cells[colcount].value == "section") {
                    console.log("Found section");
                    if (newsectline!=1) {
                        sectrow=rowid;
                        newsectline=1;
                        var rowstuff=[{
                            "Id": rowid,
                            "parentId": guiderow
                            }];
                        optionupdate= {
                            sheetId: sheetno,
                            row: rowstuff
                        };
                        console.log("optionupdate for section =", optionupdate);
                        await updateRow(optionupdate);

                    }
                    else {
                        // close off the general rows
                        var rowstuff=[{
                            "Id": rowid,
                            "parentId": sectrow,
                            "toBottom": true
                        }]
                            optionupdate = {
                            sheetId: sheetno,
                            rowstuff
                        };
                        console.log("optionupdate for section - closing off general rows =", optionupdate);
                        await updateRow(optionupdate);
                        newsectline=0;
                    }
                }
                else if (row.cells[colcount].value == "") {
                    optionupdate= {
                        sheetId: sheetno,
                        "rowId": rowid,
                        body: [{parentId: sectrow}]
                    };
                    await updateRow(optionupdate);
                }
                resolve();
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        };
    });
}

// DUMMY SLEEP FUNCTION
var sleep = function (ms) {
    let now = Date.now(), end = now + ms;
    while (now < end) { now = Date.now(); }
};

 function updateRow(optionupdate) {//Return your promise and let it be controlled outside of function
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            smartsheet.sheets.updateRow(optionupdate);
            resolve();
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        };
    })
 }


indent()
```

So when I run it I get...

```
Starting process.  Please wait...
row count is  863 . Column count is  51
j= 1 , colcount= 50 , Rowid =  1139670832965508 , Guideline rowid=  , Section rowid=  , Newguideline=  , Newsectline=
Found guideline
j= 2 , colcount= 50 , Rowid =  5643270460336004 , Guideline rowid= 1139670832965508 , Section rowid=  , Newguideline= 1 , Newsectline= 0
Found section
optionupdate for section = {
  sheetId: 6458324490184580,
  row: [ { Id: 5643270460336004, parentId: 1139670832965508 } ]
}
[Smartsheet] 2021-08-01T10:01:53.682Z[  ERROR] Request failed after 0 retries
[Smartsheet] 2021-08-01T10:01:53.683Z[  ERROR] PUT https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/6458324490184580/rows
[Smartsheet] 2021-08-01T10:01:53.684Z[  ERROR] Response: Failure (HTTP 400)
        Error Code: 1008 - Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Request body must be either a JSON object or JSON array.
        Ref ID: bqto35luphre
Unhandled rejection (<{"statusCode":400,"errorCode":1008,"me...>, no stack trace)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but clearly it's something to do with the section code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed to do is to indent the sections below the chapters, and the paragraphs below the sections.  Note that a chapter can contain multiple sections. (Also note that the example is just that. I can't give real data, sorry.)

As I had problems getting it working I thought it would be useful for someone else once I succeeded :-).  Yet to be optimised and documented.

```
//Initialise Var
var sheetno=1234567890123456;  //this is the sheet ID 
var colcount=0; 
var chap,sect,rowno;
var rowdetail="nothing";
var row_ids='';
var rowList=[];
var row_ids='';
var rowList=[];
var rowdetail='';
var guiderow='';
var sectrow='';
var optionupdate='';
var newsectline='';
var newguideline='';

// Set queryParameters for `include` and pagination
var options1 = {
      id: sheetno,
  queryParameters: {
      pageSize: 1000,
    includeAll: true
  }
};

    // Load the sheet we are interested in
async function indent() {
    console.log("Starting process.  Please wait!  This takes AAAAAges...");
    smartsheet.sheets.getSheet(options1)
    .then(async function(sheetInfo) {
        var rowCount=sheetInfo.totalRowCount;  //variable to hold the number of rows
        var totcolcount=sheetInfo.columns.length;  //variable to hold the number of columns
        var colcount=totcolcount-1;  //This accounts for arrays starting at the zero position.
        console.log("row count is ", rowCount, ". Column count is ", totcolcount)
//      console.log(sheetInfo);
        // iterate through rows in the sheet and make sure they are in the right order
        for (var i=0; i < rowCount+1; i++) {
            rowdetail=sheetInfo.rows[i].id;
            var rowloc=sheetInfo.rows[i].rowNumber;
            rowList[rowloc]=rowdetail;
        }
        // iterate through rows in the sheet
        for (var j=1; j < rowCount+1; j++) {  //change from 16 to rowCount when running in production
            var options2 = {
                sheetId: Number(sheetno),
                rowId: Number(rowList[j])
            };
            await procrow(options2,j,colcount);
            await sleep(3000);
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

function procrow(options2,j,colcount) {//Return your promise and let it be controlled outside of function
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            smartsheet.sheets.getRow(options2)
            .then(async function(row) {
                var rowid = row.id;
                console.log("j=", j, ", colcount=", colcount, ", Rowid = ", rowid, ", Newguideline=", newguideline, ", Newsectline=", newsectline, "Indent Level = ", indentlevel );
                if (row.cells[colcount].value == "guideline") {  // starting chapter level
                    console.log("Found guideline");
                    if (newguideline=='') {
                        newguideline=1;
                    }
                    else { // found a chapter heading below the start. need to remove ANY indenting knowing that the last item will have been a control and therefore we will need to come back TWO levels (outdent twice).
                        indentlevel=0;
//                      console.log("end of chapter 1 indent level = ", indentlevel);
                        optionupdate= {
                            sheetId: sheetno,
                            body :  [{"id": rowid, "outdent": 0}]
                        };
                    }
                }
                else if (row.cells[colcount].value == "section") {
                    console.log("Found section");
                        indentlevel=1;
//                      console.log("section indent level = ", indentlevel);
                        optionupdate= {
                            sheetId: sheetno,
                            body :  [{"id": rowid, "indent": 1}]
                        };
                        await updateRow(optionupdate);
                    
                }
                else {
                    indentlevel=2;
                    optionupdate= {
                        sheetId: sheetno,
                        body :  [{"id": rowid, "indent": 2}]
                    };
                    await updateRow(optionupdate);
                }
                resolve();
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        };
    });
}

// DUMMY SLEEP FUNCTION
var sleep = function (ms) {
    let now = Date.now(), end = now + ms;
    while (now < end) { now = Date.now(); }
};

 function updateRow(optionupdate) {//Return your promise and let it be controlled outside of function
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            smartsheet.sheets.updateRow(optionupdate);
            sleep(4000);
            resolve();
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        };
    })
 }


indent()
```